# Error in Spring Task Scheduler

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, method-invocation

I get this error in tomcat logs

```
org.springframework.scheduling.support.MethodInvokingRunnable.run:68 - Invocation of method '[Methodname]' on target class [class com.mypackage.classname] failed
```

When I do restart of tomcat a couple times it goes away.

Can anyone help what could be the reason or how can i resolve it?

**Updated**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"    
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.schedular"></context:component-scan>

<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="5"/>
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="15"/>
<task:annotation-driven scheduler="scheduler" executor="executor"/>

<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="mySchedular" method="process" cron="0 0/1 * * * ?"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

MySchedular is my class in the com.schedular package and the

```
<context:component-scan ...
```

creates a bean for that class with the name of mySchedular as I believe it is doing correctly.

Now when the tomcat loads this file it has to invoke the method give in

```
<task:scheduled ref="mySchedular" method="process" cron="0 0/1 * * * ?" />
```

Which is named as process in our case.

But this sometimes gives error as I have mentioned at the top. Although if we restart tomcat once or twice it starts working again.

Comment: Please provide some code at which this error occurs

Comment: Added more updates to the question as requested.

Comment: did you try to diagnose you `process()` method (e. g. print a stacktrace on exception, measure time it takes to execute)?

Comment: The process method is fine. The error comes before entering into process() method. The error is saying its MethodInvocation failure. It is actually the exception line that I copied at the top.

Comment: did you every figure out what this issue was?

Comment: Never Mind - it turned out my 'invocationException' was just the scheduling framework catching a nullPointer Error (caused by a logical error in my code) and throwing a much vaguer, less helpful error instead.